# Updating Search Indexes failing because of "rouge" invalid field handle

Tags: craft3, search, fieldtypes

I'm on the latest build 3.5.3. I created a Lightswitch field type within a Matrix field in my local dev env and called it "colorBlock". No problems there. When I recreated this in my staging env I got an error trying to save the Matrix config saying I couldn't use the name "colorBlock". So I changed it to "colorBlock1" and everything worked fine.

I'm now trying to troubleshoot a persistent **Updating Search Indexes -> Failed** alert and tracked it down to a message in my logs: `"Invalid field handle: colorBlock"`. I am not using this label for any field type I've created. When I grep all the files, I see instances of "ColorBlock" in `CustomFieldBehavior.php` and `delta.yaml`.

Any advice on how to resolve?

Comment: How/when did you create your staging environment? It sounds like project config is on? If that's the case, ``colorBlock`` would appear in staging? You might also want to try clearing storage/runtime caches?

Comment: Thanks @RitterKnight! Originally they local dev went to staging, but for various reasons, the two are running a separate DB. This is the only instance of a field handle appearing in staging after many similar actions. What's the best way to clear the storage/runtime caches?

Comment: From the CP, Utilities -> Caches. From command line, cd into the same folder as your composer/craft files are and ``./craft clear-caches/all``.  You can also do it manually going into storage/runtime folder and removing folders (eg  ``rm  -r cache``).

Comment: BTW: if local and and staging db go out of sync, the project config gets confused. Wondering if that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Clearing caches didn't work for me. Regarding config getting out of sync, I've been very careful to only sync templates and CSS between the two, so don't think that's an issue. Also, this is the only time I've seen this problem (or any problem like it).